# Как сделать MaskedTextBox в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Может кто подсказать как сделать MaskedTextBox. В wpf я ее не нашел. Хотелось бы ее использовать, так как упрощает работу.

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox

Comment: @aepot выдает ошибку System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Вызов конструктора для типа "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox", удовлетворяющего указанным ограничениям привязки, привел к выдаче исключения.": номер строки "35" и позиция в строке "14"."

Comment: Без понятия, что это значит

Comment: @aepot поэтому я и не подключаю это.